# Is it possible to stop the GPS from 'jumping' on a MT6592 phone?

Tags: gps, navigation

I'm using a MT6592 phone. On the first sight, the GPS reception is not so bad - it gets a 3D fix within 1 or 2 minutes.

There's a problem though: on apps like Google Maps, I noticed that my position 'jumps' within a range of ~30 meters. This is definitely a problem when using Google Maps for car navigation because at times I receive the wrong directions.

Is there a way to fix this? I've tried [MT GPS EPO Fix](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chxdev.mtgps) but that didn't help for the jumping issue.

Answer (score 1):

Within 30 metres is sadly within the specification of GPS, so legally your phone works perfectly fine and does not qualify for warranty (refund or repair).

The issue seems to be common with your chip, and a software fix is known for rooted devices: http://www.chinasmartphonereview.com/gps-test-and-fix-for-mt6592-octa-core/. I don't know however if this is any different from the fix you tried, but it sure is worth a shot.

1. Ensure your device is rooted
2. Download [Mobileuncle Mtk Tools](https://www.google.ch/urlhttps://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details%3Fid%3Dcom.mobileuncle.toolbox%26hl%3Dde%26referrer%3Dutm_source%253Dgoogle%2526utm_medium%253Dorganic%2526utm_term%253Dm44%2Btools%26pcampaignid%3DAPPU_1_O5ORVp2WBMKPU87vodgL&ved=0ahUKEwjdn8Dm7J3KAhXCxxQKHc53CLsQ5YQBCCYwAw&usg=AFQjCNFlSEtyiLMhD4GNkmqDjiOP84mVhg&sig2=bHO3-MnEC_kczCMgCNlZFw)
3. Launch the app and go to "Power GPS Search". Tap "GPS Set" and reboot.
4. Ensure you are connected to the internet and have all location settings enabled.
5. Launch the app again and go to "Engineer Model (MTK)" –> "Location Base Service". Tick GPS ON.

Comment: Thank you. Sadly, this method consists of largely the same things, namely downloading the EPO files to get an earlier fix.

Comment: If that doesn't work for you, then you're probably out of options.